# Can you write $R^2$ as a disjoint union of two totally disconnected sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can you write $R^2$ as a disjoint union of two totally disconnected sets?

Comment: Do they need to be open or closed?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/156/can-you-explicitly-write-r2-as-a-disjoint-union-of-two-totally-path-disconnecte

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Those answers are not really relevant, as the dimension argument that Elgar gives is invalid. Subsets of compact metric spaces can be totally-disconnected and 1-dimensional.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have finally seen the light. You were twice correct :) Even in the Euclidean setting total disconnectedness does not imply having dimension 0. I must have been thinking closed sets. As you said, there exists a subset of the plane that is totally disconnected but not zero-dimensional. For example *The example of Knaster and Kuratowski* in Williard's general topology, 29B, p. 214.

Comment: @RamiLuisto For closed sets you would be right (in general for locally compact spaces metric spaces even), not in general. The gap between totally disconnected and zero-dimensional is large. There is a famous example in the metric Hilbert cube of an infinite-dimensional subspace $X$ all of whose subspaces are either infinite-dimensional or zero-dimensional. Weirdness!

Answer (score 0):

partition $\mathbb{ QxQ}$ into two set $E$ & $F$ s.t they both are dense in $\mathbb{Q^2}$

$A =${$ (r,q) | r$ is irrational and $q$ is rational } $\cup$ {$ (q,r) | r$ is irrational and $q$ is rational } $\cup E$

$B$={$(l,m)$|  $l$ and $m$ are both irrational} $\cup F$

$A\cup B = \mathbb{R^2}$

{*this is not my final answer...I am checking it...any suggestion will be accepted}*

Comment: Neither of them is totally disconnected. A line of the form $x+y=c$ lies in $A$ if $c$ is irrational, or in $B$ if $c$ is rational.

Comment: but how??? rational + irrational = irrational ... but Irrational+ irrational can be rational

Comment: You're right, sorry. I can say only that $B$ is not totally disconnected since it contains lines $x+y=c$ with rational $c$; I cannot say anything about $A$.

Comment: no you cannot say this about B also

Comment: If $x+y=c$ and $c$ is rational, then either both $x$ and $y=c-x$ are rational, or they are both irrational. In any case $(x,y)\in B$, so the whole line lies in $B$.

Comment: yes there is a flaw...let see whether I can modify it or not